# If statement in foreach loop not working correctly

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have a `foreach` loop with an if statement inside it so that if `$value` equals `'Messages'` it should increment my variable `num1` by `1`, but the if statement doesn't appear to be working correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** If I get rid of the if statement and just echo `$value`, it will echo out the value of every section in the array.

Code:

```
 <?php
     $num1 = 0;
     foreach($inventory['Category'] as $key => $value) {
         if ($value == 'Messages') {  
             $num1++;  
         }
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: Try just a var_dump($value == 'Messages') in the loop instead of the if - if it returns false when it should return true there is something wrong in the comparison. You could then try var_dump($value) to narrow down what that variable is returning.

Comment: Are you sure that $value will contains exactly 'Messages'? I mean, without space or anything else? Do a var_dump to double check.

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump()` on `$inventory['Category'] to verify that any values are Messages first?  Otherwise the code looks fine.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would the key be?

Comment: Your syntax seems fine so `$inventory['Category']` may not be what you expect.  What is the output of `var_dump($inventory['Category']);`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) might be of use to you.

Comment: Thanks Aurelio, that solved my problem, there was a space after the value.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason `$num1` is not increasing could be because `$value`  is not 'Messages'. Try echoing `$value` variable & see.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't want to do this:

```
<?php
 $num1 = 0;
 foreach($inventory as $key => $value) {
         if ($value == 'Messages') {  $num1++;  }
 }
 ?>
```

If you array has a key called `$inventory['Messages']` this would find it.  Your original sample looks for `$inventory['Category']['Messages']`.

Comment: This will find the value `Messages` in the array `$inventory`. This would not find `$inventory['Messages']` - In order to do that, it would need to compare `$key` to `'Messages'`, not `$value`. For that reason, the OP's original sample does not look for `$inventory['Category']['Messages']`.